# Storage Spaces Direct HDD MediaType is unspecified

Tags: windows-server-2016, failovercluster, storage-spaces

I have two HP ProLiant DL380 Gen9 servers with Windows Server 2016 on which a SQL Server 2016 is to be installed in the failover cluster with Storage Spaces Direct. When I try to activat S2D via PowerShell I get the error:

WARNING: 2017/07 / 13-10: 13: 48.295 Disk number 2 ({455cd214-ecdd-7e52-b5c5-a505367c878c}, friendly name 'HP LOGICAL VOLUME') on node DB1 has unsupported media type

The HDDs as well as SSDs are set up in a RAID.
The SSDs are recognized as MediaType SSD, but the HDDs are unspecified.
Changing the MediaType via Set-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName HPLogicalVolume -MediaType HDD failed.

The HDDs and SSDs are online but without a partition and are recognized as Bus Type SAS.

How can I activate Storage Spaces direct in this configuration or where is my error?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to have supported media types with Storage Spaces Direct which is no-RAID, no-FC and no-iSCSI. Should be SATA, SAS and NVMe.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-direct-hardware-requirements

**Drives**

*Use local-attached SATA, SAS, or NVMe drives.*

You can easily workaround this issue if you say don't have compatible SAS HBA and want to use RAID controller and single driver RAID0 nodes by forcing RAID -> SAS using registry tweaking or installing third-party filter driver to do that.

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/resolving-enable-clusters2d-bus-type-support-issue-on-some-storage-controllers

I can't find the driver though...

P.S. In general I'd skip using S2D on only two nodes, it's clumsy at best: fault tolerance isn't great: cluster can't survive second disk or node crash in a row, multi-resilient disks and erasure coding aren't available.

Answer (score 5):

Right, using Storage Spaces Direct in two or three nodes configuration is not the best idea. There are a lot of solutions in this niche like HPE or Starwind. HPE Storevirtual works with two nodes and additional witness node. Starwind works with two nodes by design. https://www.hpe.com/us/en/storage/storevirtual.html

Answer (score 1):

To specify media type you need to set it with PowerShell script similar to:

```perl
Get-Physicaldisk | where size -gt 506870912000 | Set-PhysicalDisk –MediaType HDD
```

This script fails unless the disk is already a member of a Storage Pool. When your server is already a member of Failover Cluster, there is a problem, that newly created Pools are shared. Best is to create a Storage Pool before joining the cluster, change Media Type and destroy the pool. Disk type is preserved.